# Recommended data structure to store a changeable sequence with a number

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to build a FP tree, and feeling quite confused which data structure I should use to record the prefix path and its occurrence. The prefix path is a sequence recording item set like `('coffee','milk','bear')` and its occurrence is an `int` number. I post two requirements of the data structure below so that  you don't need to go deep into FP-tree:

- The occurrence of prefix path need to be searched frequently, so maybe `dict` like `{prefix_path : occurrence}` is the best way to store them.
- The prefix path need to be updated(re-rank and filter) in a conditional FP tree.

I have searched other's work in Github, and found out people would use `{tuple(['coffee','milk','bear']):occurrence}` or `{frozenset(['coffee','milk','bear']):occurrence}` to do so. However, when prefix path update, they need to change `tuple` or `frozenset`into list then change it back. I think this is quite not pythonic.

I am wondering if there is a better way to store prefix path with its occurrence.

Comment: When you do lookups, does the order of the prefix path parts matter?  That is, do you need tuple or set as the key?

Comment: @John Zwinck Yes, the order of the prefix path inside really matters. eg.  `('coffee','milk','bear')` is different from `('milk','bear','coffee')`. But the order outside between prefix paths doesn't. eg `OrderedDict{('tea','coffee'):2, ('milk',): 2}` is the same as `OrderedDict({('milk',): 2, ('tea','coffee'):2})`

Comment: It seems like `{tuple('coffee','milk','bear'):occurrence}` is the right way to go then.